# RevTex 4.1 - Extra comma in bibliography when JOURNAL field is empty

Tags: bibtex, pdftex, natbib, revtex

I have to compile a paper with RevTex 4.1 for submission purposes and I am running into trouble regarding the bibliography page.

Whenever I have a citation of a paper which has not yet been published in a journal, like most papers on arXiv, I get extra commas in the correspondent line on the bibliography page.

I am sure this is a silly mistake but I could not find the answer on Google, hence this question.

Sample tex file:

```
\documentclass[english,a4paper,notitlepage,aps,pre,10pt]{revtex4-1}
\usepackage{babel}

\begin{document}

\title{This is a sample title}

\author{Author1}
\email{author1@place1}
\affiliation{University 1}
\author{Author2}
\email{author2@place2}
\affiliation{University 2}

\begin{abstract}
This is a sample abstract.  
\end{abstract}

\maketitle

\section{Introduction}
This is a sample intro. And this is a sample citation \cite{Anand2009}.
\section{Conclusion}
This is a sample conclusion.
\bibliography{references}{}

\end{document}
```

Sample references.bib:

```
@article{Anand2009,
abstract = {Trust lies at the crux of most economic transactions, with credit markets being a notable example. Drawing on insights from the literature on coordination games and network growth, we develop a simple model to clarify how trust breaks down in financial systems. We show how the arrival of bad news about a financial agent can lead others to lose confidence in it and how this, in turn, can spread across the entire system. Our results emphasize the role of hysteresis -- it takes considerable effort to regain trust once it has been broken. Although simple, the model provides a plausible account of the credit freeze that followed the global financial crisis of 2007/8, both in terms of the sequence of events and the measures taken (and being proposed) by the authorities.},
archivePrefix = {arXiv},
arxivId = {0911.3099},
author = {Anand, Kartik and Gai, Prasanna and Marsili, Matteo},
eprint = {0911.3099},
month = nov,
pages = {21},
title = {Financial crises and the evaporation of trust},
url = {http://arxiv.org/abs/0911.3099},
year = {2009}
}
```

Sample output with pdflatex+bibtex+pdflatex+pdflatex: [image: Screenshot]

I am running an up-to-date installation of Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS with the following:

```
TeX 3.1415926 (TeX Live 2013/Debian)
kpathsea version 6.1.1
Copyright 2013 D.E. Knuth.
There is NO warranty.  Redistribution of this software is
covered by the terms of both the TeX copyright and
the Lesser GNU General Public License.
For more information about these matters, see the file
named COPYING and the TeX source.
Primary author of TeX: D.E. Knuth.

pdfTeX 3.1415926-2.5-1.40.14 (TeX Live 2013/Debian)
kpathsea version 6.1.1
Copyright 2013 Peter Breitenlohner (eTeX)/Han The Thanh (pdfTeX).
There is NO warranty.  Redistribution of this software is
covered by the terms of both the pdfTeX copyright and
the Lesser GNU General Public License.
For more information about these matters, see the file
named COPYING and the pdfTeX source.
Primary author of pdfTeX: Peter Breitenlohner (eTeX)/Han The Thanh (pdfTeX).
Compiled with libpng 1.2.49; using libpng 1.2.50
Compiled with zlib 1.2.8; using zlib 1.2.8
Compiled with poppler version 0.24.5

BibTeX 0.99d (TeX Live 2013/Debian)
kpathsea version 6.1.1
Copyright 2013 Oren Patashnik.
There is NO warranty.  Redistribution of this software is
covered by the terms of both the BibTeX copyright and
the Lesser GNU General Public License.
For more information about these matters, see the file
named COPYING and the BibTeX source.
Primary author of BibTeX: Oren Patashnik.
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks for your help, let me know if further information is needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I expected, the answer to my question is very simple.

For future reference, just replace @article by @unpublished and the problem is gone.

Answer (score 4):

The field `journal` is one of the *required* fields for entries of type `@article`. Since the entry in question appears to be available only an `arxiv` preprint, you probably shouldn't use the `@article` entry type for it. Instead, consider using the catch-all `@misc` entry type. (You might also try `@unpublished`.)

[image]

```
\documentclass[english,a4paper,notitlepage,aps,pre,10pt]{revtex4-1}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{references.bib}
@misc{Anand2009,
  archivePrefix = {arXiv},
  arxivId = {0911.3099},
  author = {Anand, Kartik and Gai, Prasanna and Marsili, Matteo},
  eprint = {0911.3099},
  month = nov,
  pages = {21},
  title = {Financial crises and the evaporation of trust},
  url = {http://arxiv.org/abs/0911.3099},
  year = {2009},
}
\end{filecontents*}
\usepackage{babel,url}
\bibliographystyle{aipnum4-1}
\begin{document}
\cite{Anand2009}
\bibliography{references}
\end{document}
```

Comment: @dd_rlwll - Was there a problem with my answer that you un-accepted it more than two weeks after I posted it and you accepted it? If so, please let me -- and others -- know about the problem.

Comment: My apologies for the late reply. I answered my own question 3 minutes before you posted the solution. I tried to accept your answer as well but apparently it is not possible to do it now.